# Scan for Wifi networks on iPhone SDK

Tags: ipad, ios4, wifi, jailbreak

I'm looking for the API to search for networks on the iPhone/iPad, and get data from them.
A private API is also OK, the app's for cydia.

I know it is possible, because I saw some wardriving apps (in the store). I want that functionality in my app too.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks,

Yvan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at redpin.org . Especially have a look to their class Sniffer.m
It is exactly what you need!